# QApplication In Non-Main Thread

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, qt4

I need to exec() a QApplication in a thread that is not main (my GUIs must be plugins that can be dynamically loaded and unloaded at runtime, so I have no access to the main thread).  Does anyone know of a (relatively) painless way to hack around Qt's restriction against starting QApplication outside of main?

I'm developing in Linux with Qt4 in C++ using gcc4.3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using QThread then you already have normal Qt event loop and can just run exec() inside QThread::run() function. While you can't work with GUI objects outside of the main thread you still can interact with them through queued signal/slot connections. Maybe you can try to store pointer to the main thread QThread object and call QObject::moveToThread() to move your GUI objects to the main thread instead of moving QApplication into another thread.

I think it's not really good idea to try to go against toolkit with different kind of hacks and kluges.

Comment: I think you may be right, VestniK - While my GUI does indeed run, it doesn't seem to actually service update() calls unless I force the OS to redraw the GUI by dragging another window around on top of it.

Comment: I found this answer useful for solving another problem, but while moving QMainWindow object from another thread to main one I received `QObject::moveToThread: Widgets cannot be moved to a new thread`

Answer (score 8):

You can start a QApplication in a PThread as below

## //main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "appthread.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  InputArgs args = {argc, argv};
  StartAppThread(args);
  sleep(10);
  return 0;
}
```

## //appthread.h

```
struct InputArgs{
  int argc;
  char **argv;
};
void StartAppThread(InputArgs &);
```

## //appthread.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "appthread.h"
#include <pthread.h>

void *StartQAppThread(void *threadArg) {
  InputArgs *args = (struct InputArgs*) threadArg;
  QApplication app(args->argc, args->argv);
  QMainWindow w;
  w.show();
  w.setCentralWidget(new QPushButton("NewButton"));
  app.exec();
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void StartAppThread(InputArgs &args) {
  pthread_t thread1;  
  int rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, StartQAppThread, (void*)&args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Patch Qt, I guess and remove the main thread check, and test if that works for you.
According to
http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-7393
that won't work on OS X/Cocoa though, as Cocoa assumes the first thread spawned to be the main/UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got something that works! It's not pretty, but it definitely does the job.

1. Create a QMainWindow derivative with all of your actual GUI code in it and overload the event() function of this class to call this->show()
2. Create a class (let's call it Runner) which will hold a pointer to your QMainWindow derivative, and give it a run function.
3. In the Runner::Runner(), start up a thread which will call Runner::run()
4. In Runner::run() (which is now running in it's own thread) construct a QApplication, and an instantiation of your QMainWindow derivative. Call the exec() function of the QApplication.
5. Now, when you want to start up your GUI, just post any event to your QMainWindow derivative, and it will show itself!

This solution seems to work very well in Linux, although it really seems to be exploiting some loophole in Qt and may not work on other platforms.  Definitely easier than patching Qt though.

Comment: Hey Boatzart, I am trying to achieve the same thing. When you say " the Runner::Runner(), start up a thread which will call Runner::run()", what do you mean. Start another QThread which would start Runner thread? But how could you start another thread without constructing QApplication?

Answer (score 2):

Adding my 2 cents with a fancy lambda and C++ threads:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t1
    (
        [&]
        {
            QApplication a(argc, argv);
            MainWindow w;
            w.show();
            return a.exec();
        }
    );
    t1.join();
}
```

Here `Mainwindow` can be your `QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is found in: git@github.com:midjji/convenient_multithreaded_qt_gui.git

then its just e.g.

```
run_in_gui_thread(new RunEventImpl([](){
        QMainWindow* window=new QMainWindow();
        window->show();
    }));
```

or whatever code you wish to run in the gui thread.

callable from any thread, at any time, while taking care of setting things up for you in the bg.