# How to use threads to instantiating multiple QApplication

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, qapplication

I found a solution to prevent `app.exec()` from blocking the main thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290909/2158231).

I tried to implement this but I got the following errors:

```
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication
```

Here is my code:

PB is a class that has a static function which initializes the GUI.

pb.cpp:

```
bool PB::Init(int argc, char *argv[],
        int ID) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    PB PB(ID); // The constructor creates an instance of the pushbutton qt object
    app.exec();
    return true; // Do I even need this because app.exec() runs an infinite loop right?

}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::thread first(&PB::Init, argc, argv, 0);
    std::thread second(&PB::Init, argc, argv, 1);

    first.join();
    second.join();

}
```

The thing is, I am initializing QApplication in the classes so it should work... I made sure that it would work with a seperate test where QApplication is not used in the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    PB::Init(argc, argv, 0);

}
```

This code works fine. So it is only when I add the thread in that I get this error.

Comment: Why do you think you need two QApplications? QEventLoop or QThread::exec() would provide event loop if that what's you need.

Comment: Don't I need QApplication just to be able to construct a QWidget? When I remove the QApplications I get `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget` error.

Comment: Sorry, but Qt widgets does not support multitheading. QWidget must be created on single (main) thread where QApplication resides. Use threads to calculate data, and pass results using Qt::QueuedConnection signals to the main thread to be visualized on GUI. Check [threaded mandelbrot example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html) about main (GUI) and worker thread communication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create `QApplication` in different thread, but you should create all GUI classe's objects in this thread otherwise you get undefined behavior. `QApplication` is singleton, so you can't create multiple instances of `QApplication` in different threads.

Comment: One point: there are no such thing as "main thread". You can safely create `QApplication` in "non-main" thead and there will be no UB. But you right, that `QApplication` is singleton. @Justin has problem when he creates second instance of `QApplication`. It doesn't depends on threads. Please, fix you answer.