# How to create QtQuick window outside the main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

What I'd like to have is a main thread that instantiates a class that extends QQuickView and moves it to a second thread.

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyClass myClassObj;

    myClassObj.init();

    return 0;
}
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
void init()
{
    MyQtQuickClass view;

    QThread* GUIthread = new QThread(this);

    view.moveToThread(GUIthread);
    QObject::connect(GUIthread, SIGNAL(started()), &view, SLOT(init()));

    GUIthread.start();
}
```

**MyQtQuickCLass.cpp**

```
void init()
{
    QQmlContext* rootContext = this->rootContext();

    // Setup view code here

    this->show();

    QGuiApplication::instance()->exec();
}
```

With something like this I get this error: 
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to QQmlContext(0x120fc60) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlEngine(0xdf6e70).

Is there a workaround? Or a way to create the QML engine directly in the second thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a QQuickView to live outside the `main()` thread, then you must:

1. Create a new `std::thread` (NOT a `QThread`, because it is a `QObject` so it mustn't be created before your `QGuiApplication`)
2. Run an `init()` function in that thread. Let it instantiate your `QGuiApplication` and start the event loop.
3. Create your `QQmlEngine`/`QQuickView`/`QQuickWidget` in that thread too.
4. Ensure that **all** of your GUI objects are accessed from that thread only.
5. Ensure that your `main()` thread doesn't create any `QObject`s until after your `QGuiApplication` has been created in your other thread.

See [How to avoid Qt app.exec() blocking main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289423/how-to-avoid-qt-app-exec-blocking-main-thread/22290909#22290909) for more details.

Comment: Understood, I quickly tried it and it works. The problem is, how can I handle the communication between the 2 threads now? Before I wanted to use signals and slots, but now the class the instantiates the pthread can't be a QObject, so it won't work. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: One possible solution is this: After you spawn the secondary thread, block your main thread until you verify that the `QGuiApplication` has been fully created. After you unblock, you can create a QObject in the main thread and set up signal-slot connections. The class that instantiates the `pthread` can't be a `QObject`, but it can create other `QObject`s.

Comment: Thanks for the valid suggestion, it solves the problems!

Answer (score 2):

`QObject`s have thread affinity to the parent `QObject`'s thread, or the current thread if they don't have a parent. Most likely -- in your example -- some `QObject`s created during instantiation of `MyQtQuickClass` have affinity to the thread in which they were created. Creating the `MyQtQuickClass` in the `GUIthread` would solve this.

**However**, all Qt windows **must** run in the same thread as `QGuiApplication`, and your application would most likely crash if you tried.

Comment: The problem is exactly that, I'm forced to create the QGuiApplication object as the very first thing in the main, so it's stuck to the main thread. Is there a way to postpone the creation of the QGuiApplication object, so that I can create it directly inside the MyQtQuickClass object?

Comment: You might be able to start a native thread (pthreads etc) and consider that one as your "main" Qt thread.