# QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have this very simple Qt code:

```
void thread_func()
{
    int a1 = 1;
    const char* a2[] = { "dummy_param" };
    QApplication app(a1, (char**)a2);

    QMessageBox msg(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "MyTitle", "Foo bar Foo bar", QMessageBox::Ok);
    msg.exec();
}
```

If I call the above function from my `main` in a `std::thread`, it brings up the dialog:

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t(thread_func);
    t.join();
}
```

...but when I close it, I get the warning message:

```
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

I've checked that the thread affinity of both `QApplication` instance and `msg` is the same. Calling the `thread_func` function directly from my `main()` (without creating a `std::thread`) removes that message.

I am using Qt 5.15.1 on Windows 10.

What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: You can't create GUI elements (e.g. `QMessageBox`) on any thread other than that on which `main` is running.  It's just not supported.

Comment: @G.M. I thought it can work, at least on windows as posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289423/how-to-avoid-qt-app-exec-blocking-main-thread

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed to operate Qt GUI directly outside the main thread(GUI thead). You can emit signals.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message says it all. Use a signal/slot mechanism to accomplish the same thing.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(){}
public slots:
    void displayMessageBox()
    {
        QMessageBox msg(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "MyTitle", "Foo bar Foo bar", QMessageBox::Ok);
        msg.exec();
        this->close();
    }
};

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker() {}
    void start() { emit askForMessageBox(); }
signals:
    void askForMessageBox();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget *widget;
    Worker *worker;
    QThread *thread(nullptr);

    widget = new Widget();
    worker = new Worker();
    thread = new QThread(nullptr);

    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::askForMessageBox, widget, &Widget::displayMessageBox);
    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::start);

    widget->show();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Example provided above.